# Can you change a state without going through the upgrade process?

Tags: corda

If I had contract and state classes placed into two different cordapp jars.

I believe if I change the contract instead, old state object references the old contract attachment by hash will throw out an error of `ContractConstraintRejection`.

But if it's the other way around, when I change the state, i.e add a new parameter. Will it impact the anything?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

It will indeed impact the transaction once the node you're transacting with receives it.

This is because your state will still have the same class name on both nodes and when the other node receives the amended state, it won't know how to deserialize the modified state and throw an exception.